# Can we access data from an api call which is made by another app in angular js

Tags: json, angularjs, angularjs-directive

There is some static data in json format available on a web page through a rest api call made by owner of that page.
Now i want to retrieve that data in my angular app as my angular controller also exists on that page.
Is that possible?
The rest api call is already made by the owner so i don't want to make a network call again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If data is open to all**

If the JSON is accessible to anyone on the internet then you can call it in with a http request.

for example http://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers.php is a page of JSON data that anyone can access, all you have to do is make the correct http request in your app and the data will come into it.

To do a http request create a controller with code like the following

```
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get("http://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers.php")
  .success(function(response) {$scope.names = response.records;});
});
```

this will add all of the data to the $scope.names.

**Note**

Code taken from w3schools [here](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_http.asp)

Comment: I can do that.But since the xhr request is made by owner itself i dont want to make another xhr request.I wanted to retrieve data from that api call itself.The only problem is that i have not made that call.Is there a way around?

Comment: Like in the example u gave above if that xhr request is made by w3schools.i just directly want to use data instead of making another reuest.And hypothetically consider that i have my controller existing on w3schools page

Comment: and yes data is open to all

Comment: I would have thought that you would have to make a request but perhaps it is possible to scrape the data off the top.

Comment: is there anything you can think of?please let me know